# SAS : How do I find nth instance of a character/group of characters within a string?

Tags: regex, sas, substring

I'm trying to find a function that will index the nth instance of a character(s).

For example, if I have the string `ABABABBABSSSDDEE` and I want to find the 3rd instance of `A`, how do I do that? What if I want to find the 4th instance of `AB`

ABAB**A**BB**AB**SSSDDEE

```
data HAVE;
   input STRING $;
   datalines;
ABABABBASSSDDEE
;
RUN;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. have you read into `regex lookaround`. `SAS` uses `PERL` regex engine.

Comment: You could also use FIND in a do loop for simple examples, altough regex is the better way for complex cases...

Comment: @gwillie No `regex` so far, but I will look into it.....I've used `index` and `find` with a combination of `substr` in the past, but this next-level complexity will probably need regex. Ty.

Comment: Sounds like a great use for `proc fcmp`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a much simplified implementation of finding N-th instance of a group of characters in a SAS character string using SAS find() function:

```
     data a;
        s='AB bhdf +BA s Ab fs ABC Nfm AB ';
        x='AB';
        n=3;

        /* from left to right */
        p = 0;
        do i=1 to n until(p=0); 
           p = find(s, x, p+1);
        end;
        put p=;

        /* from right to left */
        p = length(s) + 1;
        do i=1 to n until(p=0); 
           p = find(s, x, -p+1);
        end;
        put p=;
     run;
```

As you can see it allows for both, left-to-right and right-to-left searches.

You can combine these two into a SAS user-defined function (negative n will indicate search from right to left as it is in find function):

```
     proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.functions.findnth;
        function findnth(str $, sub $, n);
           p = ifn(n>=0,0,length(str)+1);
           do i=1 to abs(n) until(p=0);
              p = find(str,sub,sign(n)*p+1);
           end;
           return (p);
        endsub;
     run;
```

Note that the above solutions with FIND() and FINDNTH() functions assume that the searched substring can overlap with its prior instance. For example, if we search for a substring ‘AAA’ within a string ‘ABAAAA’, then the first instance of the ‘AAA’ will be found in position 3, and the second instance – in position 4. That is, the first and second instances are overlapping. For that reason, when we find an instance we increment position p by 1 (p+1) to start the next iteration (instance) of the search.
However, if such overlapping is not a valid case in your searches, and you want to continue search after the end of the previous substring instance, then we should increment p not by 1, but by length of the substring x. That will speed up our search (the more the longer our substring x is) as we will be skipping more characters as we go through the string s. In this case, in our search code we should replace p+1 to p+w, where w=length(x).

A detail discussion of this problem is described in my recent SAS blog post [Finding n-th instance of a substring within a string](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2019/06/26/finding-n-th-instance-of-a-substring-within-a-string/). I also found that using find() function works considerably faster than using regular expression functions in SAS.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm late to the party here, but in the interest of adding to the collection of answers, here's what I've come up with.

```
DATA test;
   input   = "ABABABBABSSSDDEE";

   A_3  = find(prxchange("s/A/#/",   2, input), "A");
   AB_4 = find(prxchange("s/AB/##/", 3, input), "AB");
RUN;
```

Breaking it down, `prxchange()` just does a pattern matching replacement, but the great thing about it is that you can tell it *how many times to replace that pattern*. So, `prxchange("s/A/#/", 2, input)` replaces the first two A's in `input` with #. Once you've replaced the first two A's, you can wrap it in a `find()` function to find the "first A", which is actually the third A of the original string.

One thing to note about this approach is that, ideally, the replacement string should be the same length as the string you're replacing. For instance, notice the difference between

```
prxchange("s/AB/##/", 3, input) /* gives 8 (correct) */
```

and

```
prxchange("s/AB/#/", 3, input)  /* gives 5 (incorrect) */
```

That's because we've replaced a string of length 2 with a string of length 1 three times. In other words:

```
(length("#") - length("AB")) * 3 = -3
```

so `8 + (-3) = 5`.

Hopefully that helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

```
data _null_;
findThis = 'A'; *** substring to find;
findIn = 'ADABAACABAAE'; **** the string to search;
instanceOf=1; *** and the instance of the substring we want to find;
pos = 0; 
len = 0; 
startHere = 1; 
endAt = length(findIn);
n = 0; *** count occurrences of the pattern;
pattern =  '/' || findThis || '/'; 
rx = prxparse(pattern);
CALL PRXNEXT(rx, startHere, endAt, findIn, pos, len);
if pos le 0 then do;
    put 'Could not find ' findThis ' in ' findIn;
end;
else do while (pos gt 0);
    n+1;
    if n eq instanceOf then leave;
    CALL PRXNEXT(rx, startHere, endAt, findIn, pos, len);
end;
if n eq instanceOf then do;
    put 'found ' instanceOf 'th instance of ' findThis ' at position ' pos ' in ' findIn;
end;
else do;
    put 'No ' instanceOf 'th instance of ' findThis ' found';
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `find()` function and a do loop within a datastep.  I then take that code, and place it into a `proc fcmp` procedure to create my own function called `find_n()`.  This should greatly simplify whatever task is using this and allows for code re-use.

**Define the data:**

```
data have;  
  length string $50;
  input string $;
  datalines;
ABABABBABSSSDDEE
;
run;
```

**Do-loop solution:**

```
data want;
  set have;  
  search_term = 'AB';
  nth_time = 4;
  counter = 0;
  last_find = 0;

  start = 1;
  pos = find(string,search_term,'',start);
  do while (pos gt 0 and nth_time gt counter);
    last_find = pos;
    start = pos + 1;
    counter = counter + 1;
    pos = find(string,search_term,'',start+1);
  end;

  if nth_time eq counter then do;    
    put "The nth occurrence was found at position " last_find;
  end;
  else do;
    put "Could not find the nth occurrence";
  end;

run;
```

**Define the `proc fcmp` function:**

Note: If the nth-occurrence cannot be found return 0.

```
options cmplib=work.temp.temp;

proc fcmp outlib=work.temp.temp;

  function find_n(string $, search_term $, nth_time) ;    

    counter = 0;
    last_find = 0;

    start = 1;
    pos = find(string,search_term,'',start);
    do while (pos gt 0 and nth_time gt counter);
      last_find = pos;
      start = pos + 1;
      counter = counter + 1;
      pos = find(string,search_term,'',start+1);
    end;

    result = ifn(nth_time eq counter, last_find, 0);

    return (result);
  endsub;

run;
```

**Example `proc fcmp` usage:**

Note that this calls the function twice.  The first example is showing the original request solution.  The second example shows what happens when a match cannot be found.

```
data want;
  set have;  
  nth_position = find_n(string, "AB", 4);
  put nth_position =;

  nth_position = find_n(string, "AB", 5);
  put nth_position =;
run;
```